# Unable to get cart total in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

I am doing some custom work in WooCommerce WordPress plugin. I am unable to get cart total. How can I do this.

```
$total         = $woocommerce->cart->get_total();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
global $woocommerce;
$amount = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total+$woocommerce->cart->tax_total;
```