# Get cart total as a float number in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce,

```
<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
```

gives me €1,750.00

How can I get this as a floating number so I can multiply it?

I tried every solution in these two SO questions:

[Unable to get cart total in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975972/unable-to-get-cart-total-in-woocommerce)

[woocommerce - Get Cart Total as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063173/woocommerce-get-cart-total-as-number)

All outdated and not working. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can refer to  [WooCommerce `WC_Cart` official documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#288-298)

This should work:

```
WC()->cart->get_total("anything_else_than_'view'");
```

**Explanations:**

Thanks to [**btomw**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337057/btomw) that pointed out that an argument need to be defined in `WC_Cart` `get_total()` method. If you call this method without defining an argument *(that should be anything else than 'view' string)*, the output is going to be the formatted total price, as `'view'` default argument will be used by this method. So if you want to get a float value `(non formatted)`, set as argument anything else that is not 'view', even an empty string like `''`. As you can see on [this method documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_total), it's for backwards compatibility since WooCommerce 3.2.

Comment: Specifically, it's important to include an argument, literally any argument other than `"view"`, when calling this function.

Comment: Thanks. Is there also now a quick way to format the float back to `€1,750.00` WooCommerce format?

Comment: Same function no argument I believe

Comment: @SarPutnik May be it should be better to only keep your edit to avoid people to be confused.

Comment: @RafRasenberg you can use `wc_price()` function with the amount as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the answer of [**Sar Putnik**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11854874/sar-putnik), With `WC_Cart` object you **can directly access properties** like `total`, which gives a non formatted number:

```
$total = WC()->cart->total;

// Testing output
var_dump($total);
```

It will give the same output if using `$total = WC()->cart->get_total("");`

> Note that, since WooCommerce 3, on other WooCommerce instance objects **you can't access properties directly**… But some few classes as `WC_Cart` still allow that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $total = $cart_item['line_total'];
```

This gives you all the subtotal lines